# How to apply themes in XML file, when I called it once it must be applied entirely to all the components in app?

Tags: android, styles, themes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/blueborder</item>
<item name="android:button">@drawable/rounded_edittext</item>
<item name="android:textAppearance">@android:drawable/alert_light_frame</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</style>  

<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="CustomTheme">
</style>  

<style name="JobViewHeader" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

This is my code, I have done style and theme in XML. I have applied background resource (ie)  `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittext);` in Java. It has been changed especially shapes. I do not understand what is wrong here.

Same, how should I apply theme in XML file? If I called once it should apply to all the components entirely, Android.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In, your application's AndroidManifest.xml, add a theme attribute `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` to `<application>` tag.

Comment: <application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"> // I have already added. No changes i have seen :-(

Comment: Yeah i have added after you said @wingman but no changes. I guess, have to call button style in resources. I mean, in my above code, i have created button style but i dint call it. I have no idea , whether i am right or wrong .